# Curl'ing an URL impossible due to Cloudflare?

Tags: curl, cloudflare

I want to curl https://www.mixcloud.com but I get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 19 Aug 2017 12:55:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d513ab50b3cd934646911c88c779e27061503147301; expires=Sun, 19-Aug-18 12:55:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.mixcloud.com; HttpOnly
vary: Cookie, User-Agent, X-Requested-With, X-Ignore-Block
x-request-id: 4663cfbe69ba49f49be15cac32d6b69f
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-content-type-options: nosniff
location: /deprecated/
content-security-policy: default-src https: data: blob:; script-src https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline'; img-src https: data: blob:; media-src https: http: blob: data:; connect-src http: https: ws: wss:;
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
set-cookie: s=l5zbsmmijbhnextg7z6u7ovuwsah7m4q; Domain=.mixcloud.com; expires=Tue, 17-Aug-2027 12:55:01 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=315360000; Path=/; secure
set-cookie: redirref=; Path=/
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 390d43ccfcc86b5b-LHR
```

Does that mean the site is behind Cloudfare now and it's impossible to grab the HTML via curl or jQuery?

Comment: Did you try to add switch `L` in your curl command? `curl -L www.mixcloud.com`.

Comment: `-L` means follow redirect. I tried with curl command and it works. Not tried in PHP though. BTW, I get 301 instead of 302.

Comment: I guess that's similar to PHP's CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION? Struggling with a open_basedir error atm. https://pastebin.com/s5LxBmYd

Comment: I can confirm the curl command working fine. Damn PHP

Comment: Thanks, using `shell_exec` now.